# How to fit all the content coming from web services in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have implemented UIWebView and displaying the contents coming from web services,Here is the code below

```
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
webView.dataDetectorTypes = YES;
webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
webView.delegate = self;

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:delegate.S_Title];
request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

However when i scroll down to bottom, it didn't scroll to show the complete content displayed by webview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, after you have loaded content in the `UIWebView` you can use it's `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method to ask the html document for its height. This is a little tricky but should work.

You can do something like this:

```
NSInteger height = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
    @"document.body.scrollHeight"] integerValue];
```

The scrollheight mught not be the best. You have a couple of options. Experiment with the document properties mentioned [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/)